# How to plot data with negative value in a clear way using ggplot?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, scale

For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
df=data.frame(
 year=2001:2020,
 pre=c(8.5018000 , -7.7160000 ,  7.0916000 , -5.0360000 , -7.7912000
 , -11.8490000 , 26.1540000,  -9.2820000 , -8.5530000 ,  0.5976900
,   6.6069000,  -6.2534000, -11.4280000 , -0.0079124  , 6.0739000
,  14.7270000 , 29.4790000, -15.8340000 ,  4.1739000, -19.6560000),
 tmp=c(0.702760, -1.077300, -1.058300 ,-0.882200 ,-0.491940,  2.048100,
 -0.999390,  0.308870,  1.107600, -0.042847,  0.452430 ,-0.329630,
0.636950,  1.484700,  0.434400,  0.079248, -0.503850, -0.710800,
0.025189, -1.183900)
)
```

If I just plot `tmp`,its variation can be observed clearly.Howexver,if I add the `pre` to ggplot,the tmp can not be observed clearly.

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x=year,y=tmp),col='red')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x=year,y=tmp),col='red')+
  geom_line(aes(x=year,y=pre))
```

[image]

How to plot it clearly?

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Thanks for all reply and comments.I try to rescale them because of some reasons.The following problem is that it not give legend automatically.

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x=year,y=scale(tmp)),col='red')+
  geom_line(aes(x=year,y=scale(pre)),col='blue')+
  geom_text(aes(x=year,y=scale(tmp)),label=2001:2020)+
  geom_text(aes(x=year,y=scale(pre)),label=2001:2020)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2001:2020,name=NULL)+
  scale_y_continuous(name=NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: That's because limits of the  variable `pre` are around 10 times bigger than `tmp`. You have to re-scale one of them.

Comment: … or use separate plots.

Comment: Thanks a lot！Rescale and facet are both  good ways.@RobertoT  @Limey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* add a secondary axis:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(year, pre/10)) +
  geom_line(col = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = tmp)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "tmp",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x * 10, name = "pre")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

[image]

Or use facets:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -year), aes(year, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(name~., scales = "free") +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("black", "red")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: If the intention is to compare the temporal patterns of the two series, it might be better to add `nrow = 1` to the `facet_wrap` so that they're on top of each other instead of side by side.

Comment: @JonSpring fair point. Probably just as well using `facet_grid` in that case with the shared x axis. I agree that looks better now.

Comment: @Jon Spring
I do want to compare them! I want to know if they vary in the same trend or not.

Comment: @Allan Cameron Thanks a lot!  But if I have more than 2 variables, is re-scale them a good way? For example, there are [pre] [tmp] [soil] . It couldn't add third axis.

Comment: @jackywang in that case, facets may be your best option - the faceting solution will work with any number of series.

Comment: @Allan Cameron  Big thans!(But my editor told me that I'd better show more information in one figure so that he can arrange the paper easily)

Comment: @jackywang OK, but those are your options. You can have all the lines in the same panel on the same scale, which gives you the problem of one or more of the lines having too little resolution. _Or_ you can use multiple y axes (though 2 should be your limit here). _Or_ you can have multiple panels in the same size of figure using facets. You can't have three lines with three different scales without using one of these three options.